# Dynamically pipe user input into a variable for ls bash

Tags: bash

I have the following one sed liner that I use to prettify the output of lsing all my .desktop files.

`ls -1 | sed -e 's/\.desktop$//' | sed -e 's/\org.gnome.//' | grep "$name" | head -1`

Currently I have a read command that I pipe into that $name variable for input. Can you give me some ideas on how to make it dynamically output or autocomplete what im typing as app launchers like Rofi or others do?

Comment: Look at `readline` for tab-completion. I'm not aware of any terminal based auto-suggestion while you type. You may search for "command line auto-complete Linux" and see what turns up. Understand that `ls` to 4-pipes, 2 invocations of `sed` and one each of `grep` and `head` is far from ideal. The `find` command can likely handle all your needs.

Comment: Thanks man, when i said autocomplete I meant the ls command would look like it was auto completing the ls search you were typing up, not command auto completion just to clarify.

Comment: Sure, I understood you to mean you start typing and then either a list or similar is shown with all the commands that begin with that prefix. I apologize if I got it wrong. After using the Linux desktop for nearly two-decades, I'm not aware of anything that provides for the command line what you would see, for example in a text editor. No technical reason it can't, but by convention, command lines usually rely on `readline` using `tab` to cycle through or display the prefixed commands. `history` allows searching through past command lines and shells provide shortcuts for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [`peco`](https://github.com/peco/peco) utility. (It's also packaged for [several distributions](https://repology.org/project/peco/versions).)

From its github page:

> `peco` can be a great tool to filter stuff like logs, process stats, find files, because unlike grep, you can type as you think and look through the current results.

The [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) "commandline fuzzy finder" utility ([repos](https://repology.org/project/fzf/versions)) is similar:

> It's an interactive Unix filter for command-line that can be used with any list; files, command history, processes, hostnames, bookmarks, git commits, etc.

---

There's a list of other options at: https://alternativeto.net/software/peco/